# Disable remote shutdown on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-access, remote-shutdown

i want to disable remote shutdown to prevent the timer (on my internet cafe) from shutting down a certain pc (obviously, that pc should not be shutdown... diskless setup). how?

Obviously, im improvising. the timer is on a netbook and i want client to use the server pc on a different windows 8.1 account (non-admin). Anyways, just focus on the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change access to who can perform remote shut downs by changing the local security policy.  However, only machine administrators have this right be default.

- From Start type `Local Security Policy` and it should pop as you type
- Expand `Local Policies`
- Select `User Rights Assignment`
- In the right pane, double click `Force Shutdown from a remote system`
- Select the users to have access (default is admin)
- Click `Apply`